# how to get field names to each be on their own line

Tags: sql, vim

There’s a plugin called [SQLUtilities](https://github.com/vim-scripts/SQLUtilities) that will format your SQL nicely; however, it’s really bothering me that it cannot put a column on it’s own separate line:

[image]

The result that I want is this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggling the g:sqlutil_align_comma setting aligns by comma but leaves the first field on the same line as the SELECT statment:

```
:SQLUToggleValue g:sqlutil_align_comma
:1,$SQLUFormatter
```

Sample result:

```
  SELECT f.id   
       , f.firstname    
       , f.lastname 
       ...
```

SQLUtilities has additional documentation via

```
:help sqlutilties
```

Or full screen

```
:tab help sqlutilities
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `gq {motion}` to autoformat it.

Here's the documentation:

> gq{motion}            Format the lines that {motion} moves over.
>                         Formatting is done with one of three methods:
>                           1. If 'formatexpr' is not empty the expression is
>                              evaluated.  This can differ for each buffer.
>                           2. If 'formatprg' is not empty an external program
>                              is used.
>                           3. Otherwise formatting is done internally.

---

Or you can use substitute:

```
:s/) + '|','|'/) + '|'\r,'|'/
```

Please replace `\r` with appropriate file ending type.

Comment: `\n` will insert a null character in the substitution; use `\r` which will be translated to the canonical line ending.